# What is the best way to check if a record has been approved in Apex?

Tags: apex, approval-process

We're trying to limit the amount of DMLs on a highly used Object. Aside from putting a flag on the object like "Approved__c" and updating this in the Approval, is there an efficient way (similar to the Approval class) of checking if a record has been Approved at least once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using query on ProcessInstance with subquery on ProcessInstanceHistory. I have added logic assuming need to check this on one record at a time. Based on requirement this can be bulkified.

```
Id recordId = '0010K02122bN7J8QAK';
Boolean isRecordApproved = false;
ProcessInstance pi = [SELECT ID, ProcessDefinition.Name, (SELECT  StepStatus FROM StepsAndWorkitems )
 FROM ProcessInstance WHERE TargetObjectId = :recordId]; // Add filter ProcessDefinition.Name if you need to check if record is approved for specific approval process
for(ProcessInstanceHistory ph : pi.StepsAndWorkitems) {
    if(ph.StepStatus == 'Approved') {
        isRecordApproved = true;
        break;
    }
}
System.debug('Is Record Apprved :  ' + isRecordApproved);
```